# Joining Tables with id VS saving the text

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have two table one is **accounts** table and **account group** table. currently I am using the auto increment id as foreign key in the accounts table but my question is I have multiple tables where it will join with accounts table and I need to retrieve account group name in a view where there is 20 union all queries which it join to the accounts table.

```
        SELECT acc.name,accgrp.groupName,bill.supplier,bill.amount
        FROM bills bill
        INNER JOIN accounts acc ON acc.accId=bills.accId
        INNER JOIN accountGroup accgrp ON accgrp.groupId=acc.groupId
        UNION ALL
        .....
```

What is the correct way to save the data in accounts table saving id is the best approach or saving the group name is best approach. If i used id as foreign key and join in 20 union all is it make my query slower? or saving group name in my accounts table and retrieve it without join make my query faster?

Comment: Your approach of using a `join` is the correct approach.  The `union`s are suspicious and suggest a deficiency in your data model.

Comment: if there is more than 100,000 records in the table. will join is the best approach to retrieve the group name ? or should i save group name as foreign key in the accounts table instead of id?

Comment: 100.000 records should not be a problem if the mysql is configured right and there is an index on that field in every table. The ID is good, but to get the fastest result, use the same field type and length in both table for that field.

Comment: Yeah i did like you have said thanks alot.